# Openlayers zooming into custom map

Tags: openlayers

I am investigating using OpenLayers for a web application. Basically OpenStreetMap or Google Maps don't zoom in enough, so what I want to achieve is that when you zoom to the maximum level and click zoom again that a custom map image is loaded.

If that is not possible then the alternative would be to do an overlay which would appear only on the maximum zoom level, and once clicked they would go through to another map, probably SVG based.

Which one of these would be more feasible? Any feedback welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it can be done, but it's tricky to configure.

You can render your own openstreetmap tiles with Mapnik. As it's based on vector source you could zoom in further.

Alternatively, you can add a vector layer (this will become SVG or VML) or a static image layer, and only make this visible at a high-enough zoomlevel. However, because your base-layer is OSM or Google Maps, the Map can not zoom in further than the maximum zoomlevels of the base layer.

What you could do, is override the default OpenLayers.Layer.OSM layer, set the max zoom levels higher ([although this is not good practice](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SettingZoomLevels)) and stop fetching OSM tile-images at higher zoomlevels, and add custom behaviour (load tiles from your own server, or use the vector layer option). You have to override the proper methods somewhere in the class hierarchy (`OpenLayers.Layer.OSM` extends `OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ` extends `OpenLayers.Layer.Grid` etc..)

```
OpenLayers.Layer.MyOSMLayer = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Layer.OSM, {
    initialize: function(name, options) {
        options = OpenLayers.Util.extend({
            numZoomLevels: 19 + 4,
        }, options);
        var newArguments = [name, url, options];
        OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.prototype.initialize.apply(this, newArguments);
    },

    // @override from XYZ
    getURL: function (bounds) {
        var xyz = this.getXYZ(bounds);
        if ( xyz.z > 19 ) {  // override url on higher zoomlevel
             return "http://myserver/white.png";
        }
        // else default behaviour: super.getUrl()
        return OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.prototype.getURL.apply(this, [bounds]);
    },

    CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Layer.MyOSMLayer"
})
```